# Files get committed with the wrong file encoding

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-extensions

We are UTF8 with BOM in most of our code files.

However, some code files get into the git repository as plain ASCII. I haven't figured out how/why. It's mostly existing files. From what I can tell they do not have to been modified (i.e. code changes) to become converted to ASCII.

It causes problems since we are using latin1 characters in comments and text.

I'm trying to track down how/when the files are converted, but am a bit lost. We are using Visual Studio (2015 & 2017) and an application called "Git Extensions".

Is there a setting in Visual Studio, in git or in Git Extensions that can change the file encoding?

Answer (score 1):

In GitExtensions there is a setting for [Files content encoding](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-4.1/settings.html#files-content-encoding). It is used when a file is open in GitExtensions internal editor.